# C++ writing to std::string* var from file

Tags: c++, string, file, pointers, char

Actually I'm experiencing a problem with saving single char to string*. I've got a function like this:

`void save(std::string* x, const std::string& file);`

Actually I'm taking each digit from the file using loop and assign it to char ch;

So, the question is how can I append this char to string*? If I make temp string and add each symbol to this string and after just do `strcpy` or just `x = temp`, I'm getting  segmentation fault.

Would you tell me how to deal with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: Can you post some code..?

Comment: std::string s="test"; s += "_appended_text"; /* is (more or less) equal to **/ std::string* ps = &s; *ps += "_more_appended_text"; // and strcpy shouldn't be needed for pure std::string handling

Comment: of course this works for chars as well: std::string s="test"; s += 'c'; /* is (more or less) equal to **/ std::string* ps = &s; *ps += 'C';

Comment: `*x += temp;` is the correct code to modify the caller's `std::string`, passed in by pointer as `x`.

Comment: you seem to try to assign something to the std::string-POINTER x which doesn't seem to be right; try to assign to the VALUE the pointer is pointing to by DEREFERENCING it previously

Comment: Its more usual to pass objects by reference (like your second parameter) and to avoid pointers as much as possible. Eg: `void save(std::string& x, const std::string& file);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never directly alter a std::string's buffer, because it has its own method of managing the memory.

Instead, you should use the `append()` method:

```
char temp;
//...
if(x)  //check for nullptr
{
    x->append(1, temp);  //appends the char 'temp' once
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're creating a local string and then assigning it to `x` - something like this:

```
std::string temp;
// Add to temp
// ...
x = &temp;
```

The problem with this is that `x` is effectively an out parameter and you're assigning it to a local. When the function goes out of scope the local (`temp`) will be destroyed, and `x` will now point to the destroyed region of memory. This will give you an access violation.

You're best bet is change `save` so that it returns the string. Something like this:

```
std::string save(const std::string &file)
{
  std::string temp;
  // Do stuff...

  return temp;
}
```

Now the string will be correctly copied (or moved if you're C++11) back to the caller. You can use `push_back` to append characters to `temp`.

If you don't want to return the string then pass a reference to a user supplied string and fill that:

```
void save(std::string &x, const std::string &file)
{
  char temp;
  x.push_back(temp);
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
std::string output;
save(output, "path/to/my/file);
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't return the temp string. As you mentioned above, x will be pointing to the destroyed part of memory, so that's the problem. Is there any way how to copy string with no return?

Comment: @Alex - I've updated my answer to show an example using references.

Comment: @Alex That's not true. A string's *value* is the contents of the string. Returning a string by value works just fine. This is safe: `std::string add1(const char *j) { string s = j; s+="1"; return s; }`. You are returning the contents of the string by value.

Comment: @Alex as David points out, returning a `std::string` is fine as the copy/move constructor takes care of transfering the memory.